# What is returned by select count statement?

Tags: javascript, mariadb

I am trying to run the following SQL statement with MariaDB and Javascript. (Node.)

```
select count(*) from users where user_id = 100
```

It appears to run, but I have no idea what is being returned.

```
const count = await connection.query('select count(*) from users where user_id = ?', [userId]);
console.log(count);
```

This prints: `0,meta`

What is being returned here, and how do I get some useful data out of that? I would expect that the sql `count` query should return `1`.

This is what `console.dir(count)` produces:

```
[
  { 'count(user_id)': 1n },
  meta: [
    ColumnDef {
      collation: [Collation],
      columnLength: 21,
      columnType: 8,
      flags: 129,
      scale: 0,
      type: 'BIGINT'
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm still confused about what this exactly means or how should I interpret this.

Comment: `COUNT` returns a single integer.

Comment: You are looking for a `count` of all records with `user_id = 100` - you will get a number (count) of all matching records (in the sample case, zero records).  To get useful data, you want to `select * from users where ....` as it fetches all columns from the matching records on that table

Comment: Are you sure you have a record on the DB where their `user_id = ` (the userId from the variable) ?

Comment: If there's a user with that ID, it returns 1. If there's no user with that ID, it returns 0. So it's a way of testing whether the user ID is already assigned.

Comment: What MariaDB connection library are you using?

Comment: The mariadb Node module documentation contains stuff that does not make sense, but it seems that the `meta` property contains metadata like column names from the SELECT result set

Comment: If you do `console.dir(count)` instead of `console.log()` it may make more sense.

Comment: OH wait I bet I know what happens: you're getting back a result array, and the array itself has an additional property, "meta". Again, use `console.dir()`, because `console.log()` is going to turn the `count` value into a string first.

Comment: I've added another comment - would anyone mind explaining to me what is being represented here?

Comment: @Pointy where can I find that documentation?

Comment: I'm looking on the `npm` page for the `mariadb` package, specifically the ["promise documentation"](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/promise-api.md)

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, that page is absolutly not easy to find

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
const count = await connection.query('select count(user_id) as ? from users where user_id = ?', ['count', userId]);

const actualCount = count[0]['count'];
console.log(`actualCount=${actualCount}`);
```

---

## Full Answer

This is how I eventually solved this.

Let's break it down:

This is what we get back from the query:

```
[
  { 'count(user_id)': 1n },
  meta: [
    ColumnDef {
      collation: [Collation],
      columnLength: 21,
      columnType: 8,
      flags: 129,
      scale: 0,
      type: 'BIGINT'
    }
  ]
]
```

This is an array object containing 2 elements. The first element is an un-named  object, the second is an array object which has the name 'meta'. This contains some meta data, so we will ignore it.

The first object is accessed using `returnedData[0]`. In other words:

```
returnedData[0] = { 'count(user_id)': 1n }
```

I have no idea what `1n` is about, but this seems to convert seamlessly into an integer. The problem is how to access that integer? There are two ways.

We could use the key `'count(user_id)'`. We can obtain this from `Object.keys(count[0])`. So we can do `count[0][Object.keys(count[0])]`.

I don't really like this. A better way is to modify the query like this:

```
const count = await connection.query('select count(user_id) as ? from users where user_id = ?', ['count', userId]);
```

We have explicitly specified the name of the key which should be returned.

Now, we get the actual data using this:

```
const actualCount = count[0]['count'];
console.log(`actualCount=${actualCount}`);
```

Comment: Apparently `1n` means the type is `BigInt`. So if you want to do any logic involving the returned value, use `BigInt` types to compare with.

Comment: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#:~:text=A%20BigInt%20value%2C%20also%20sometimes%20just%20called%20a%20BigInt%2C%20is%20a%20bigint%20primitive%2C%20created%20by%20appending%20n): "A BigInt value, also sometimes just called a BigInt, is a bigint primitive, created by appending n to the end of an integer literal, or by calling the BigInt() function (without the new operator) and giving it an integer value or string value."